# Faulty Example for the Function 'periodicreturns'?

Tags: matlab

For my own data set, I would like to use the function periodicreturns which is included in Matlab since 2006 (and I use the 2015 edition) but I cannot get it to work and don't find anything about that problem online. In a first step, I would like to get the example code running.

This is the example code provided by MathWorks (https://ch.mathworks.com/help/finance/periodicreturns.html):

```
Dates = datetime(2015,1,1:10,'Locale','en_US')';
Prices = [0.01 0.03 0.1  -0.05  0.02 0.07 0.03 -0.01 -0.02 0.01]';
TotalReturnPrices = table(Dates,Prices);
TotalReturn = periodicreturns(TotalReturnPrices)
```

Unfortunately, I always get this error message:

```
Undefined function 'isnan' for input arguments of type 'table'.

Error in periodicreturns>dailyreturnspersecurity (line 85)
trprc(isnan(trprc(:,2)),:) = [];

Error in periodicreturns (line 50)
        tmptr{i} = dailyreturnspersecurity(trprc(:,[1,i+1]));
```

I tried the following:
- A variation where a cell is chosen as the input instead of a table (leads to a different error message)
- restarting with a fresh workspace
- googling but only finding problems with NaN's present in the data set
- adapting the function, so it does not check for NaN's (since there are none present in the example), which led me to a new problem:

```
Undefined operator '-' for input arguments of type 'table'.

Error in periodicreturns1>dailyreturnspersecurity (line 93)
    tr(tindex,2) = (pp - pp0)/pp0;

Error in periodicreturns1 (line 50)
        tmptr{i} = dailyreturnspersecurity(trprc(:,[1,i+1]));
```

Any ideas what I'm missing?

Comment: that's weird, works fine on my end. do the following: do "edit periodicreturns.m", and put a checkpoint right after the line "TableFlag = istable(TRPC);" to see what's going on. Theoretically, that is where the function transforms the data in order to do some treatments to transform the table into an array, but it seems this part is not being done properly in your system. Report back to say what the value is for TableFlag

Comment: Thanks for your reply.
I cannot find the line TableFlag = istable(TRPC) in the code for the function periodicreturns (when entering "edit periodicreturns.m"). Do I have a different version of that function? I am a bit confused by how this can be different. It would make sense to check for the type of input first, though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function [`periodicreturns`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/finance/periodicreturns.html) *currently* supports [`table` variables as inputs](https://www.mathworks.com/help/finance/periodicreturns.html#mw_6e89f947-955d-4e9d-a6d9-59cd12e1cf82), but didn't support them in the older version of MATLAB you're using. If you have a MathWorks account, you can view the older documentation for R2015b [here](https://www.mathworks.com/help/releases/R2015b/finance/periodicreturns.html), which specified only numeric matrices as valid inputs for the function. The [very next release (R2016a)](https://www.mathworks.com/help/releases/R2016a/finance/periodicreturns.html) is when support for table inputs was added.

Passing a cell array as input doesn't appear to be supported either. Here's how the older documentation says the input should be formatted:

> Number of observations (`NUMOBS`) by number of assets (`NASSETS + 1`) matrix of total return prices for a given security. Column 1 contains MATLAB® serial date numbers. The remaining columns contain total return price data.

So you need to use [date numbers](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/datenum.html) instead of `datetime` objects.

Comment: Okay, in that case it should at least support cells, right? When I change the third line to 

`TotalReturnPrices = {Dates,Prices};`

then I get this error message:

`Error using sortrows>sort_cell_back_to_front (line 129)
Some cells in X contain non-scalar values and cannot be sorted.

Error in sortrows (line 87)
        ndx = sort_cell_back_to_front(x_sub, col);

Error in periodicreturns (line 42)
trprc = sortrows(trprc);`

Comment: @Xenopaia: I added a response for that to the answer.

Comment: Converting the dates by using datenum and then adding the two arrays to a matrix solved the problem. Thank you!